# Как дать привелегии на таблицу в другой схеме для обращения к ней в функции?

Tags: oracle, plsql, права-доступа

Создаю функцию, которая обращается запросом к таблице другого пользователя (пользователь Б). Но при создании ошибка, что таблицы не существует.

Функция создаётся под пользователем А. Синоним есть, привелегии на `select` для таблицы пользователя Б у пользователя А есть, но не создаётся.

Если выполняю такое:

```
grant all privileges to userA;
```

То функция создаётся без ошибок. Но так конечно неправильно.

Выдача привелегий:

```
alter, delete, insert, select, update, references, debug, flashback, on commit, query rewrite to public
```

на эту таблицу тоже ничего не даёт.

Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привелегии пользователю А на таблицы пользователя Б выделены *через роли*.

Выделенные через роли привилегии действуют в SQL и анонимных блоках.
Но они **не действуют** в именованных блоках PL/SQL кода - функциях, процедурах итд.

Надо выделить привелеги напрямую, то есть так:

```
grant select on B.tab to A;
```

Comment: не, я это сразу нагуглил, не помогает, я не только напрямую на пользователя, я даже уже на паблик выдал права на эту таблицу, но функция компилится только если выдать админские права

Comment: я дурак не на ту таблицу смотрел